# Where do I get iostream for g++ in fedora 19

Tags: io, g++, fedora

I'm trying to compile xmacro which I downloaded from http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/.

I'm running Fedora 19 LXDE.

**question:** Where do I get iostream.h?  It's missing. I see some packages the include iostream.h.  The package version number compat-gcc-34-c++.i686 doesn't match g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 20130603.  Should it?

I'd think iostream.h would be included when I downloaded the compiler.

I have installed gcc-c++ , libx11-devel, & libxtxt.

**question:** did I get the right version of c++?  What is Compatibility GNU Compiler Collection?

```
$ yum search "compat-gcc"
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
=========================================== N/S matched: compat-gcc ============================================
compat-gcc-34.i686 : Compatibility GNU Compiler Collection
compat-gcc-34-c++.i686 : C++ support for compatibility compiler
compat-gcc-34-g77.i686 : Fortran 77 support for compatibility compiler

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

I get:

```
$ make
g++ -O2  -I/usr/X11R6/include -Wall -pedantic -DVERSION=0.3 xmacroplay.cpp -o xmacroplay -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lXtst -lX11
xmacroplay.cpp:57:22: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [xmacroplay] Error 1




$ yum whatprovides '*/iostream.h'
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
compat-gcc-34-c++-3.4.6-29.fc19.i686 : C++ support for compatibility compiler
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/c++/3.4.6/backward/iostream.h



cxxtools-devel-2.2-1.fc19.i686 : Development files for cxxtools
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/cxxtools/iostream.h



gap-devel-4.6.4-2.fc19.i686 : GAP compiler and development files
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/gap/src/iostream.h



gap-devel-4.6.5-1.fc19.i686 : GAP compiler and development files
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/gap/src/iostream.h



glibmm24-devel-2.36.2-2.fc19.i686 : Headers for developing programs that will use glibmm24
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/giomm-2.4/giomm/iostream.h



marisa-devel-0.2.2-2.fc19.i686 : Development files for marisa
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/marisa/iostream.h



mingw32-glibmm24-2.36.2-2.fc19.noarch : MinGW Windows C++ interface for GTK2 (a GUI library for X)
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/giomm-2.4/giomm/iostream.h



mingw64-glibmm24-2.36.2-2.fc19.noarch : MinGW Windows C++ interface for GTK2 (a GUI library for X)
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/giomm-2.4/giomm/iostream.h



root-cint-5.34.07-1.fc19.i686 : CINT C++ interpreter
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/root/cint/cint/include/iostream.h



root-cint-5.34.10-1.fc19.i686 : CINT C++ interpreter
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/root/cint/cint/include/iostream.h



me ~ $ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 20130603 (Red Hat 4.8.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

me ~ $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iostream.h` is the old, pre-standard name for a header in what would later become the C++ standard library. The modern, standardised name is just `iostream`, without the `.h`.

The best solution would be to go through the source and change `iostream.h` to `iostream` everywhere. You might encounter other problems though, if the C++ code you're trying to compile is truly ancient. On the other hand it might work fine, with a few warnings. Give it a try and see what happens.

If it doesn't work, you might find that the "compat-g++" package (which has the very old 3.4 version of g++) handles this old code better than 4.8 does.

Comment: Use the gcc34 command to compile with the old 3.4 version.  Errors & warnings were reduced but not eliminated. I may have to add a ++ to my c skills.